# How to get the sum of a variable, for only one value of another variable, using dplyr in R

Tags: r, dplyr, sum

I have a dataframe like this

```
df <- data.frame(
time = rep(c("2002", "2003", "2004", "2005", "2006"), 10),
DHB = rep(c("HB", "CM", "CC", "CT", "WA"), 10),
ethnic = rep(c(rep(c("M"),5, rep(c("T"), 5))), 5),
pop = rnorm()
)
```

I want to add a new variable, totpop, which is the sum of 'pop', where ethnic = T. I tried this code

```
df <- df %>%
mutate(totpop = filter(ethnic== "T") %>% sum(pop))
```

I get this error message `Error in UseMethod("mutate_") : 
  no applicable method for 'mutate_' applied to an object of class "function"`  Which I assume means I have my statements out of order, or I'm doing something else stupd. Can someone help me get this right? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Your sample data throws an error; fixing that first you can do the following

```
set.seed(2018);
df <- data.frame(
    time = rep(c("2002", "2003", "2004", "2005", "2006"), 10),
    DHB = rep(c("HB", "CM", "CC", "CT", "WA"), 10),
    ethnic = rep(c(rep("M", 5), rep("T", 5)), 5),
    pop = rnorm(50))

df %>%
    filter(ethnic == "T") %>%
    summarise(totpop = sum(pop));
#
#     totpop
#1 -2.987487
```

Or depending on what you want to do next, you can also group by `ethnic` and then calculate the group-wise `pop` sums:

```
df %>%
    group_by(ethnic) %>%
    summarise(totpop = sum(pop));
## A tibble: 2 x 2
#  ethnic totpop
#  <fct>   <dbl>
#1 M       -1.03
#2 T       -2.99
```

Comment: @r2evans But `ethnic` is not `TRUE`/`FALSE`, unless I've misunderstood you.

Comment: So true, caffeine ... levels ... waning. You could do `sum((ethnic=="T")*pop)`, though it doesn't really save a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Similar to other answer - but if you want to add column with mutate instead of summarize:

```
set.seed(2018)
df <- data.frame(
  time = rep(c("2002", "2003", "2004", "2005", "2006"), 10),
  DHB = rep(c("HB", "CM", "CC", "CT", "WA"), 10),
  ethnic = rep(c(rep("M", 5), rep("T", 5)), 5),
  pop = rnorm(50))

df <-  df %>%
  group_by(ethnic) %>%
  mutate(totpop = sum(pop))
```